# Strange type promotion in arithmetic operation

Tags: python, cython

Why this cython function:

```
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

def foo(np.uint32_t b):
    cdef np.int32_t a = 0


    if a-b <0: return 0
    else: return 1
```

returns 1, for foo(1)?
I compiled similar code in C, and didn't observe both operands (a, b) had been promoted to unsigned int.

Comment: Did you try to look at the generated C code to see how that's being translated?

Comment: You right, it seems operand are declared correctly but  result is somehow strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` is the correct result; the signed operand should be converted to the corresponding unsigned type.

> #### 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> [...] 
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I must have  missed some information how printf works. `uint32_t b=1; int32_t a=0; printf("%d\n",a-b);` give correct -1.

Comment: @MarcinBurz `printf` doesn't know the type of its arguments. If you use the correct format specifier `%u` you'll see the actual value 4294967295.

Comment: Once again, many thanks. I have learned a lot by analyzing this short example.